# Getting Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 while using npm run serve command

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to create a website using node.js and vue.js. So to run the code, I first change the directory to my project directory, in terminal and use `npm run serve` command. But still I am getting an error. I have even re-downloaded `npm` libraries using `npm install` command.
Error is,

`vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
 10% building 5/5 modules 0 activeevents.js:174

      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`
      ^

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1448:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:17)`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

typing `unset HOST` on terminal fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's about ip of x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0.

Add

```
127.0.0.1       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

to /etc/hosts file. Then the problem is gone. I met the same problem today.

Answer (score 0):

echo $HOST
to check env variable value for $HOST

if its not set to 'localhost' use export to set to 'localhost'
export HOST="localhost"

Answer (score -2):

If you are using iTerm2, try updating it to the latest version. Version 3.3.2 fixed for me.

Comment: Can you please give more details to the answer, e.g giving the version that "works"